# How to change width of height of SVG with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a CRA React App.

How do you change the width and height of an SVG without preserving aspect ratio (e.g. width 500px height 10px)?

```
import ornament from '../../assets/img/ornament.svg';

<img src={ornament} style={{width: '500px', height: '20px'}} />
```

This preserves aspect ratio and only changes size. I want it to transform to 500px width and 20px height. So original 400px 400px => 500px 20px.

EDIT: example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/40xj3zv5w7 , the image gets really small instead of 400px width and 10px height.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing the problem. Ideally a static page and not a CRA React App.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you, added the example.

Comment: Something like this? <img src={ornament}#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none)) style={{width: '500px', height: '20px'}} />

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers or alternatively edit the image file itself so it has preserveAspectRatio="none" on the root node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't resize only width, like a regular image, because svg are **vectors**, and they **scale**. You need to set **preserveAspectRatio(none)**

When you are working with just **HTML**, you can do tis:

```
<img src="your.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))" />
```

With **React**, you can do it like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ornament from '../../assets/img/ornament.svg';

class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const svgPath = `${ornament}#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))`;
    return (
      <img src={svgPath} width="500px" height="20px"/>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `transform: scale(sx, sy)`

```
sx = 500/400
sy = 20/400
```

Comment: I was looking to modify all of my svgs at once because I changed my root font-size and wanted to resize my svgs proportionally. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

The least complicated method I found:
https://codepen.io/copist/pen/vLLmPB

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" x="0px" y="0px" width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" style="null" class="whateverClassYouWish" >

.whateverClassYouWish {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
}
```